# how to overwrite a file on Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

Uploading works fine.

When trying to upload a file with the same name (with the intention to replace it) I get a 403 auth error.

```
"Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access ..."
```

I have set the storage permissions to full access:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that my rules were wrong.

Changing the rules solved the problem

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that may help .

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/6